# Imprimir text de un input select en lugar de su value

Tags: php, html, mysqli, input, html-select

Tengo el siguiente `<select>` como parte de un formulario con varias opciones que el usuario puede seleccionar y enviar, lo que se aloja en una base de datos y luego se imprime en forma de publicación. Mi problema es que al imprimir estos valores escogidos por el usuario, no logro hallar una forma de hacer que se imprima el text de la opción escogida del select en lugar de su `value`. A continuación el código del `select`:

```html
   <p>Provincia</p>
   <select name="provincia" onchange="cambia_localidad()">
      <option value="0" selected>Ciudad Autónoma de Buenos Aires</option>
      <option value="1">Provincia de Buenos Aires</option>                                
      <option value="2">Córdoba</option>
      <option value="3">Santa Fe</option>
      <option value="4">Mendoza</option>
      <option value="5">Tucumán</option>
      <option value="6">Entre Ríos</option>
      <option value="7">Salta</option>
      <option value="8">Misiones</option>
      <option value="9">Chaco</option>
      <option value="10">Corrientes</option>
      <option value="11">Santiago del Estero</option>
      <option value="12">San Juan</option>
      <option value="13">Jujuy</option>
      <option value="14">Río Negro</option>
      <option value="15">Chubut</option>
      <option value="16">Neuquén</option>
      <option value="17">Formosa</option>
      <option value="18">San Luis</option>
      <option value="19">Catamarca</option>
      <option value="20">La Rioja</option>
      <option value="21">La Pampa</option>
      <option value="22">Santa Cruz</option>
      <option value="23">Tierra del Fuego</option>
   </select>
```

El select asociado al anterior mediante la funcion javascript "cambia_localidad"

```
<div class="loc2">
                                        <p>Localidad</p>
                                        <select name="localidad"> 
                                            <option value="-">-</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                        <script type="text/javascript">
                                            var localidad_1=new Array("-","Zona Norte","Zona Oeste","Zona Sur", "Zona Gran La Plata");
                                            var localidad_2=new Array("-","Gran Córdoba","Gran Río Cuarto","Colón","Punilla","Gral San Martín", "Otros");
                                            var localidad_3=new Array("-","Rosario","La Capital","General López","General Obligado", "San Lorenzo", "Otros");
                                            var localidad_4=new Array("-","Capital","Guaymallén","Las Heras","Godoy Cruz","San Rafael", "Maipú", "Otros");
                                            var localidad_5=new Array("-","Capital","Cruz Alta","Tafí Viejo","Chicligasta","Yerba Buena", "Otros");
                                            var localidad_6=new Array("-","Paraná","Concordia","Gualeguaychú","Uruguay","Federación", "Colón", "Otros");
                                            var localidad_7=new Array("-","Capital","Gral José de San Martín","Orán","Anta","General Güemes", "Rivadavia", "Otros");
                                            var localidad_8=new Array("-","Capital","Oberá","Igüazú","Eldorado","Guaraní", "San Ignacio", "Otros");
                                            var localidad_9=new Array("-","San Fernando","Comandante Fernández","General Güemes","Libertador Gral San Martín","Chacabuco", "Almirante Brown", "Otros");
                                            var localidad_10=new Array("-","Capital","Goya","Santo Tomé","Paso de los Libres","Bella Vista", "Ituzaingó", "Otros");
                                            var localidad_11=new Array("-","Juan Francisco Borges","Banda","Río Hondo","Robles", "Otros");
                                            var localidad_12=new Array("-","Capital","Rawson","Chimbas","Rivadavia","Pocito", "Santa Lucía", "Otros");
                                            var localidad_13=new Array("-","Dr. Manuel Belgrano","El Carmen","San Pedro","Ledesma","Palpalá", "Humahuaca", "Otros");
                                            var localidad_14=new Array("-","General Roca","Bariloche","Adolfo Alsina","Avellaneda","San Antonio", "Otros");
                                            var localidad_15=new Array("-","Rawson","Escalante","Biedma","Futaulefú","Cushamen", "Otros");
                                            var localidad_16=new Array("-","Confluencia","Zapala","Lácar","Pehuenches", "Otros");
                                            var localidad_17=new Array("-","Formosa","Pilcomayo","Patiño","Pirané", "Otros");
                                            var localidad_18=new Array("-","Juan Martín de Pueyrredon","General Pedernera","Junín","Chacabuco","Ayacucho", "Coronel Pringles", "Otros");
                                            var localidad_19=new Array("-","Capital","Belén","Valle Viejo","La Paz","Tinogasta", "Otros");
                                            var localidad_20=new Array("-","Capital","Chilecito","Arauco","Famatina", "Otros");
                                            var localidad_21=new Array("-","Capital","Maracó","Realicó","Utracán", "Otros");
                                            var localidad_22=new Array("-","Güer Aike","Deseado","Lago Argentino","Corpen Aike", "Otros");
                                            var localidad_23=new Array("-", "Río Grande","Ushuaia","Tolhuin");
                                            

                                        
                                            var todaLocalidad = [
                                            [],
                                            localidad_1,
                                            localidad_2,
                                            localidad_3,
                                            localidad_4,
                                            localidad_5,
                                            localidad_6,
                                            localidad_7,
                                            localidad_8,
                                            localidad_9,
                                            localidad_10,
                                            localidad_11,
                                            localidad_12,
                                            localidad_13,
                                            localidad_14,
                                            localidad_15,
                                            localidad_16,
                                            localidad_17,
                                            localidad_18,
                                            localidad_19,
                                            localidad_20,
                                            localidad_21,
                                            localidad_22,
                                            localidad_23,

                                            ];

                                            function cambia_localidad(){ 
                                                var provincia 
                                                provincia = document.publishform.provincia[document.publishform.provincia.selectedIndex].value 
                                                if (provincia != 0) {
                                                mi_localidad=todaLocalidad[provincia]
                                                num_localidad = mi_localidad.length 
                                                document.publishform.localidad.length = num_localidad 
                                                for(i=0;i<num_localidad;i++){ 
                                                    document.publishform.localidad.options[i].value=mi_localidad[i] 
                                                    document.publishform.localidad.options[i].text=mi_localidad[i] 
                                                }   
                                                }else{ 
                                                document.publishform.localidad.length = 1 
                                                document.publishform.localidad.options[0].value = "-" 
                                                document.publishform.localidad.options[0].text = "-" 
                                                } 
                                                document.publishform.localidad.options[0].selected = true 
                                        } 
                                    </script>
```

Luego imprimo la opción elegida en un *echo* trayendo el parámetro desde la base de datos.

```
if(isset($_POST['publicar'])){
            $usuario = $_SESSION['usuario'];
            $id = $_SESSION['id'];
            $provincia = $_POST['provincia'];
            $localidad = $_POST['localidad'];
            $currency = $_POST['currency'];
            $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
            $fee = $_POST['fee'];
            $operation = empty($_POST['operation']) ? NULL : $_POST['operation'];
            $p2p = empty($_POST['p2p']) ? NULL : $_POST['p2p'];
            $f2f = empty($_POST['f2f']) ? NULL : $_POST['f2f'];
            $method = $p2p.' '.$f2f;

            $query = "INSERT INTO anuncios(usuario, id, fecha, provincia, localidad, moneda, cantidad, comision, operacion, metodo)
            VALUES('$usuario', '$id', now(), '$provincia', '$localidad', '$currency', '$quantity', '$fee', '$operation', '$method')";

            $ejecutar = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);

    <?php
    $CantShow=10;
        $compag = (int)(!isset($_GET['publishShow'])) ? 1 : $_GET['publishShow'];
        $TotalReg = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM anuncios");
        $totalr = mysqli_num_rows($TotalReg);
        $TotalRegistro = ceil($totalr/$CantShow);
        $IncNum = (($compag +1)<=$TotalRegistro)?($compag +1):0;
        $consult = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM anuncios ORDER BY id_pub DESC LIMIT ".(($compag-1)*$CantShow)." , ".$CantShow);
        //$consultA = mysqli_query($conexion, $consult);
        while($lista = mysqli_fetch_array($consult)){
            $userid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $lista['id']);
            $usuariob = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = '$userid'");
            $use = mysqli_fetch_array($usuariob);
    ?>
    <div class="publishShow">
            <div class="publishContainer">
                <span>En: <?php echo $lista['provincia']?></span>,<span><?php echo $lista['localidad']?></span> 
            </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Lo que pretendo es que al realizar esto, se imprima el text y no el value (es decir, por ejemplo "Formosa" en lugar del "18"). No se si es posible lograr esto pero realmente me sería de mucha ayuda, ya que preferiría no cambiar los value al tener vinculado este input select con otro mediante una función javascript a partir de los value.
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices pero, ¿Podrías añadir también el código que estas empleando para imprimir ese valor como dices?

Comment: Claro. Lo añadiré a la pregunta.

Comment: Ya edité la pregunta con el correspondiente código que faltaba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No podemos observar como estas presentando los datos en tu php o que contenga tu función JS, pero para obtener el texto y ID esto te ayudara a darte una idea:

```
function cambia_localidad(){
    var id_provincia = document.getElementById('provincia').value;
    console.log(id_provincia);
    var provincia = document.getElementById('provincia');
    var selected = provincia.options[provincia.selectedIndex].text;
    console.log(selected);
}
```

Si el proceso lo estas haciendo a nivel del servidor, envia el ID y el texto desde JavaScript para ahorrarte complejidad.

Comment: La función cambia_localidad está asociada a otro select mediante el cual, al elegir una provincia, se desplegan los datos correspondientes asociada a la misma. Ya actualicé la pregunta con los datos que faltaban, especialmente en la presentación en PHP de los mismos.

Comment: Ahora que veo tu PHP estas guardando en tu tabla **anuncios** la provincia, pero no estas guardando el texto, estas guardando el ID, luego cuando haces tu SELECT esta mostrando el ID `echo $lista['provincia']`  porque eso fue lo que guardaste trato de entender.
Ahora bien, aqui lo que podrias hacer es agregar otra funcion onchange (`onchange="cambiar_localidad();Llenar();"`), que cuando la cambies se vaya llenando un  `<input type="hidden"/>` asi cuando envias el formulario tambien se envie por post el texto.